# How to resolve ArcGIS for Desktop Error (SDE has lost its connection with underlying DBMS[ORA-03114:not connected ORACLE])?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

[image: ORACLE Error]

How to resolve this issue when user leaves the system idle for one hour and again trying to connect Database, It encounters the Connection error message and then user should close the ArcGIS and restart it again.

Is there any temporary solution to make the DBMS connection active for one user if needed to stay more than one hour idle and work again?

Thanks

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the help, Is there any temporary solution to make it active database connection for one user if needs to stay that connection alive more than one hour idle.

Comment: This is not my area of speciality so I will defer to others, but is this actually the same question (or just related to it)?  To make clear what you are asking I always recommend having [ONE question mark in the title and ONE question mark in the body of your Question](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question).

Comment: @PolyGeo I updated my question and this is the actual question i'm looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions.
The recommended would be direct connect.
If application server connection is required use the oracle setting...
[Connection pooling timeout](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_03114.htm).
See also the arcsde connection settings here in the [esri help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_up_a_connection_to_Oracle/002n00000038000000/)